# How to send document paramaters to Docusign envelope

Tags: php, docusignapi

Can we, using the PHP API, send extra parameters that, otherwise are needed to be filled in by the user? So for example, we have a field 'address' in the PDF. We already know the address in the application so we want to prefill that. Is this possible?

```
    $config = array(
        'integrator_key' => 'asdf',
        'email' => 'asdf',
        'password' => 'asdf',
        // The version of DocuSign API (Ex: v1, v2)
        'version' => 'v2',
        // The DocuSign Environment (Ex: demo, test, www)
        'environment' => 'www',

    );


    $client = new DocuSign_Client($config);

    echo $current_user->user_email;

    $role = new DocuSign_TemplateRole('Bulk Recipient', $current_user->user_firstname.' '.$current_user->user_lastname, $current_user->user_email);
    $roles = array( $role );

    $signatureService = new DocuSign_RequestSignatureService($client);
    $result = $signatureService->signature->createEnvelopeFromTemplate('asdf', 'asdf',  'sent', $roles);
```

**Update:**

I added tabs to the data and a field to the template in docusign, labelled `Adres`. In send the following data to to docusign and got a file to sign without the added data. Guess I'm still doing 'something' wrong here.

Bellow the data array.

```
 ["templateId"]=>
  string(36) "1e9517bf-51c3-4e40-8bd0-600fe3a35bdf"
  ["status"]=>
  string(4) "sent"
  ["templateRoles"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["roleName"]=>
      string(14) "Bulk Recipient"
      ["name"]=>
      string(15) "Roel Veldhuizen"
      ["email"]=>
      string(27) "someemail@gmail.com"
      ["tabs"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["textTabs"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["tabLabel"]=>
            string(5) "Adres"
            ["value"]=>
            string(18) "Some example adres"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Note there are two issues:

1. Supplying your data to DocuSign for future use in a "tab" on the document.
2. *Placing* the tab on the document where you want the information to appear.

The simplest is if you already know where the tab should appear on the doc. In that case, include the tab, with the data and location information in your [Envelope.Create](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm) call. See the [tabs section](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tab%20Parameters.htm) of the Request Body. Eg, you'd use a [text tab for the address line.](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm)

You can also have either the human or DocuSign locate the tab in the right place on the document, then use an API call to populate it with the data. Look at anchoring and templates if this is of interest.

Comment: i don't fully understand the required fields, I would guess that I can prefill a field addid in the template. The documentation suggests that the posistions attributes are require and thus I custom place it in the PDF? Also, I updated the question with the current state https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text Tab.htm